# Is it possible to directly change the local variable values from an Array or any java implementation?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

```
      String monRegHrs="0.00"; 
      String monPotHrs="0.00";
      String monNpotHrs="0.00";
```

String[] varArray = new String[]{monRegHrs, monPotHrs, monNpotHrs};

I want to be able to change the value of the local variables ex monRegHrs from 0.00 to a new value.

Check if the element name is "monRegHrs"
if yes monRegHrs="hello"

Is this possible to manipulate local variables like this in java ? if so how ?

Comment: **What** element name? The name is not preserved in the array. Use a `Map`? And `monRegHrs = "hello";` - **what** are you asking?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have a set of local variables which are strings, named as in the code block above, right? And you have an array of strings which correspond to the variable names, right? Now, what triggers the replacement of a value in one of the variables?  The short answer is "yes, you can assign local variables". Now what logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: There are about 40 of those variables monReg..tueReg..wedReg..so on .. I want to put those variables in some sort of structure and initialize them depending on my logic in the loop. I don't want to set the values of these variables individually since they are about 40 to 50 in total.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplistic way of handling this is that for all variables, you will need to create a seperate method that will change the variable, then subsequently change the element of the array, and any additional things you may want to add for (for anything that's coupled with the variable).

```
public SetmonRegHrs(String value) {
monRegHrs = value;
varArray[0] = value;
}

public SetmonPotHrs(String value) {
monPotHrs = value;
varArray[1] = value
}

public SetmonNpotHrs(String value) {
monNpotHrs = value;
varArray[2] = value;
}
```